# Чи є український нерозмовний відвідник до слова "мямлить"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

[Тут](http://www.unlimited-translate.org/uk/dictionaries/russian-to-ukrainian/translate/%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.htm) знаходжу лише розмовний відповідник:

> **мямлить** (говорить неразборчиво) разг. **мимрити**

Однак цікавить, чи є НЕрозмовний відповідник до слова "***мямлить***".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можна сказати [бурмотати (бурмотіти)](http://sum.in.ua/s/burmotaty). Цікаво, що [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/mymryty) не подає це слово як розмовне. Всі інші [синоніми](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) бачимо з позначкою розм.